# What is the WP_Internal_Pointers core class?

Tags: core

The [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_internal_pointers/) does not explain it very well and I would like to understand what it is and why it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It implements the pointers feature, a UX change that was introduced in v3.3 to help *point* at new features when you first encounter them

[image]

You can use this yourself by enquing the `wp-pointer` script then using code similar to this:

```js
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    $('#menu-appearance').pointer({
        content: '<h3>Edit The Appearance</h3><p>Edit the appearance of your Wordpress theme.</p>',
        position: {
               edge: 'left',
               align: 'center'
           },
        close: function() {
            // Once the close button is hit
        }
    }).pointer('open');
});
```

`WP_Internal_Pointers` assists the WP Admin PHP in creating the admin pointers used by WordPress itself, however, it appears those pointers are no longer used. The functions that implement each pointer are empty, and the class is preserved for backwards compatibility.

While pointers still exist as a feature, they've fallen out of fashion in modern WordPress core development.

Comment: I could not imagine a better explanation. Thanks.